# QWebView get response

Tags: python, qt, webkit, pyside

I have a python code with PySide that has a QWebView that shows google maps. 
I just want to get the response each time that I do any request using the QWebView widget.

I have searched info but there is no reference about getting a response with PySide. If you need me to paste some code I will but I just have a simple QWebView  widget.

EDIT: You asked me for the code:

```
from PySide.QtCore import *
from PySide.QtGui import *
import sys


import pyside3

class MainDialog(QMainWindow, pyside3.Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainDialog,self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        token_fb=""
        #self.Connect_buttom.clicked.connect(self.get_fb_token)
        self.Connect_buttom.clicked.connect(lambda: self.get_fb_token(self.FB_username.text(), self.FB_password.text()))
        #self.connect(self.Connect_buttom, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.get_fb_token)

        #Change between locate and hunt
        self.MapsButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.select_page_index(0))
        self.HuntButton.clicked.connect(lambda: self.select_page_index(1))
        ###########################


        self.webView.setHtml(URL)
    def select_page_index(self, index):  # To change between frames
        self.Container.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

I need the response from: `self.webView.setHtml(URL)` because depending on the response my app has to do one thing or other.

Comment: If you put the code in question maybe we can help you.

Comment: The `webView.setHtml()` method only `Sets the content of the web view to the specified html.`. I don't understand what you mean by "response from: self.webView.setHtml(URL)", what kind of response are you expecting?

Answer (score 0):

Function `QWebView.setHtml()` has no response in the sense that it doesn't return anything.

Maybe you want to listen to all links that are clicked and do something custom with it.

```
web_view = QtWebKit.QWebView()
web_view.page().setLinkDelegationPolicy(QtWebKit.QWebPage.DelegateAllLinks)
web_view.linkClicked.connect(your_handler)
```

Or maybe you want to do something when loading has finished. This is done by:

```
web_view = QtWebKit.QWebView()
web_view.loadFinished.connect(your_handler)
```